# Application and Proxy server password Encryption

Tags: encryption, squid, proxy-server

I have a proxy server and I am making an application for the internet. I have no idea, the username and password exchange in between proxy server and client can be encrypted or not? If yes what encryption squid uses? I am curious to send my username and password using encryption. I have done with base64 authorization string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a corporate environment it's great to use Kerberos or NTLM authorization type to implement a secured authorization process. This is first option (more details here: https://serverfault.com/questions/106846/squid-authentication-encryption).

The second option is to use HTTPS_PORT directive in Squid, so your clients will be able to establish a *fully* encrypted SSL-connection to the proxy-server *(http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection — not just authorization, so since this moment you can use even plain-auth one)*. 
To implement this Squid should be compiled with **--enable_ssl** flag, server should have a FQDN and attached to that domain name certificate.
Example:
https_port 3143 cert=/etc/squid3/ssl/cert.pem key=/etc/squid3/ssl/private.key
Note, that certificate should be exactly in PEM format and private key shouldn't be locked with password. You may get a free and legit one from StartSSL, to example. Or you may use a self-signed one, but it's not a great idea.

There are few limitations:

1) HTTPS-proxy *(do not confuse it with proxy, which simply supports CONNECT method)* is well supported only by Firefox and Chrome at this time.

2) It works only in cooperation with proxy auto-configuration (PAC) file, more details here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy